# apache derby + jpa

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, derby

I have embedded derby database and i work with jpa. This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence 
    version="2.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="pers">

        <class>entities.Leverancier</class>
        <class>entities.Prijsproduct</class>
        <class>entities.Product</class>


    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What should i change or add to get this working. When I run my code now I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named pers
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:33)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:19)
```

Comment: What is your persistence provider?

Comment: What are going to use as the JPA runtime provider (e.g. Hibernate, EclipseLink, ...)? You need to mention it in `persistence.xml`.

Comment: well you don't really need to mention it in persistence.xml *as long as* you put just one JPA implementation in the CLASSPATH. The question stands though, as to which one is being used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `persistence.xml` is not correct. Look at a sample below:

```xml
<persistence-unit name="MyAppPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">    
    <!-- This is where you mention your JPA runtime provider e.g. it's EclipseLink here -->
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>    

    <class>mypkg.MyEntity</class>

    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/my_schema"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pass"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

You also have to make sure that you put your JPA provider jar files (along with the derby-client jar) in the classpath.

Comment: <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

which jar files then?

Comment: @user999379: This should help you get started with JPA, EclipseLink, and Derby: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html#installation